# Java: Google+ OAuth Invalid Header

Tags: java, oauth, google-plus

I'm trying to get a Google+ user's info using

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json

I pass the access token I previously obtained:

```
URL googleURL = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json");

            URLConnection googleConn = googleURL.openConnection();
            googleConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);   
            googleConn.setDoOutput(true);

            **googleConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);**

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(googleConn.getInputStream()));

            String result = "";
            while(rd.ready())
                result += rd.readLine();
            rd.close();
```

But it gives me the HTTP error code 401 (invalid headers).

Is this the right way to pass the access token in the header?

```
googleConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

To access Google+ profile information you actually want to use the people get API: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me  You may want to check out the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) or play with it in the [API Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=plus&_v=v1&_m=people.get&userId=102817283354809142195).

Also, you're coding at a much lower level than you need to. While you can use the REST endpoint directly, things will be a lot easier if you use the [official client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/). If you go this route, there's even a [Google+ starter project for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/).

If you'd like to continue low level you should pass the access token in with OAuth prefix instead of Bearer. Your resulting HTTP request headers will look something like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/102817283354809142195

Authorization:  OAuth ya29.BHES61Rxr4Cq-Elcfpvx_2oWC443fMOEQV9iS5-M7ZjJ6xk
```